# Spark on standalone cluster throws java.lang.illegalStateException

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I hava a app and read data from `MongoDB`.
If I use `local` pattern, it runs well, however, it throws `java.lang.illegalStateExcetion`  when I use `standalone cluster` pattern

With `local` pattern, the SparkContext is `val sc = new SparkContext("local","Scala Word Count")`

With `Standalone cluster` pattern, the SparkContext is `val sc = new SparkContext()`  and submit shell is `./spark-submit --class "xxxMain" /usr/local/jarfile/xxx.jar --master spark://master:7077`

[image]

It trys 4 times then throw error when it runs to the first `action`

My code

```
  configOriginal.set("mongo.input.uri","mongodb://172.16.xxx.xxx:20000/xxx.Original")
  configOriginal.set("mongo.output.uri","mongodb://172.16.xxx.xxx:20000/xxx.sfeature")
  mongoRDDOriginal =sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(configOriginal,classOf[com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat],classOf[Object], classOf[BSONObject])
```

I learned from this example 
 [mongo-spark](https://github.com/plaa/mongo-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/ScalaWordCount.scala)

I searched and someone said it was because of `mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.2`, but either I up the version to `mongo-hadoop-core-1.4.0` or down to 'mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.1', it didn't work.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution.
Because each of my workers have many cores and `mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.2` doesn't support multiple threads, however it fixed in `mongo-hadoop-core-1.4.0`. But why my app still get error is because of "intellij idea" cache. You should add `mongo-java-driver` dependency, too.